# How would you get a string of characters from an array in c?

Tags: arrays, c

I am trying to parse data from the user. I need to get a certain number from the user.

And I do not mean like with strstr(). I mean more like characters 9-12 in an array.

For example:

```c
char array[15] = "asdfghjkbruhqw";
                          ^--^
```

I cannot figure out a way to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this char array already filled out with the data?

Comment: I don't get what you mean. Do you need the index of "bruh" in that string? Or do you need to find what the content of the string is from 9 to 12?

Comment: yes, it is filled.

Comment: @altermetax I need the content.

Comment: Then @vmp's answer does what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use strcnpcy, in the second parameter you pass the starting position:

```
char array[15] = "asdfghjkbruhqw";
char dest[10] = "";
strncpy(dest, &arr[9], 3);
```

Answer (score 2):

A "string" in C behaves just like any other array, so in order to retrieve a subset of the string you must manually copy each element from a source to destination array. There are a few ways of going about this:

**Simplest option**

```
char my_source_array[15] = "asdfghjkbruhqw";
char my_dest_array[5];

int offset_start = 8; /* index of "b" in "bruh" */
int num_chars = 4;

for (int i = 0; i < num_chars+1; ++i) {
  my_dest_array[i] = my_source_array[offset_start+i];
}
my_dest_array[num_chars] = 0; /* don't forget to null-terminate */
```

**Slightly more advanced**

```
char my_source_array[15] = "asdfghjkbruhqw";
char my_dest_array[5];

int offset_start = 8; /* index of "b" in "bruh" */
int num_chars = 4; /* number of chars in "bruh" */
memcpy(my_dest_array, my_source_array+offset_start, num_chars*sizeof(char));
my_dest_array[num_chars] = 0; /* don't forget to null-terminate */
```

Comment: May want to *nul-terminate* the `my_dest_array`, e.g. `my_dest_array[num_chars] = 0;` So that `my_dest_array` can be treated as a string.